# How to know the maximum memory usage of a non-daemon program?

Tags: process, memory

As a simplest case, I have a executable file which prints"Hello, world" and then exits. How to know the maximum memory usage of it during its execution? Could I even get a memory usage graph of that process?

Answer (score 2):

You could use '/usr/bin/time', in the example below we use perl to consume a chunk of memory. This gives a good level of detail to see what the process consumed. If you want to monitor what is going on, see the example beneath that where 'pmap' is used on a pid. The bulk of the pmap output is omitted, but the final line will show the memory usage summary.

```
$ /usr/bin/time --verbose perl -e 'my $a = "a" x 919200000;'
    Command being timed: "perl -e my $a = "a" x 919200000;"
    User time (seconds): 0.19
    System time (seconds): 0.38
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%*emphasized text*
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.57
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1798908
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 449020
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 2
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

pmap:

```
$ pmap -x $( pgrep firefox ) 
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
...
00007fffa75fc000       8       8       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
00007fffa75fe000       8       0       0 r----   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4       0       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
---------------- ------- ------- -------
total kB         1865700  548748  422532
```

To collect just the final line, you could use tail -1, for the final line. If you want the memory totals only, then awk could be more appropriate, remove as appropriate:

```
$ pmap -x $( pgrep firefox ) | awk '{ if( $_ ~ /^total/ ) { printf( "%d %d %d\n", $3, $4, $5 ); } }'
1976996 595644 478532
```

Comment: What line (using `time`) give memory usage? is it `Maximum resident set size`?

Comment: Failed to explain what line in time.

Comment: The line you're looking for is max RSS `Maximum resident set size (kbytes):`